# ImportXML return empty

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I tried to webscrape the content title of post in this website : https://www.hortidaily.com/sector/553/greenhouse/

using Google Sheets Importxml function.

All posts are written in the same format :

```
<a class="article" href="link1">
 <img src="img1.jpg" align="default" border="0" class="indexdefault">      
    <h1>Titre1</h1>
    <p>Texte1</p>
</a>
```

ImportXML function with Xpath = :

- //a[@class ='article']/@href return link1 : ok 
- //a[@class ='article'][1]/img/@src return img1 : ok 
- //a[@class ='article'][1]/h1 return #NA (imported content is empty) eventhough the XPath is working in chrome XPath Helper...

Although //h1[1] return the title of the first article, the problem I do not understand why //a[@class ='article'][1]/h1 doesn't work and I want to be sure the h1 I get is the h1 under the first `<a class="article" href="link1">`

I have tried almost everything I could imagine, do not find the issue. I need some help !

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the value of `h1` in the 1st `a[@class ='article']`.
- You want to know that why `//a[@class ='article'][1]/h1` returns `#NA`.

If my understanding is correct how about this answer?

#### Reason of issue:

```
<div id="hoofdartikelen">

  <a class="article" href="link1">
    <img src="img1.jpg" align="default" border="0" class="indexdefault">
    <h1>Titre1</h1>
    <p>Texte1</p>
  </a>

</div>
```

In my investigation, for above HTML data, it seems that the tag name `a` of `<a class="article" href="link1">` is the issue. For example, when the tag name is modified to `div`, it could confirmed that `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class ='article'][1]/h1")` worked.

And also, it seems that at above HTML, the tags `h1` and `p` are not the children of the tag `a`. So the following formulas work.

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@id='hoofdartikelen']/h1[1]")

=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@id='hoofdartikelen']/p[1]")
```

But, `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@id='hoofdartikelen']/img[1]/@src")` doesn't work. It is required to be `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@id='hoofdartikelen']/a[1]/img/@src")`. So it seems that the tag `img` is the child of `a`.

#### xpath samples:

From above results, in your case, I think that the following xpath samples might be suitable.

- `//div[@id='hoofdartikelen']/h1[1]`
- `//h1[1]`
- `//a[@class ='article']/../h1[1]`

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: Dear Tanaike, thx very much for your help !
Unfortunately see my post, this solution have already been found... I want to be sure than when I extract the text in h1 it is the text under the link of the article... Also I cannot imagine there is a bug in ImportXML and would like to understand why my XPath doesn't work and what's wrong !

Comment: @Benoit de Combaud I apologize that I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize again.

Comment: thx a lot for your help and taking time to analyse the solution. Your answer looks right, h1 is not the children of a, however I do not understand as we have a <a href = ...> open tag then the <h1>...</h1> and then the </a> close tag. Is it a bug or I did not understand what is a children in XML ?

Comment: @Benoit de Combaud I think that your consideration is correct. For example, by modifying to `<img src="img1.jpg" align="default" border="0" class="indexdefault"></img>`, when above HTML is tested at ["XPath Tester"](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html), `//a[@class ='article'][1]/h1` returns `<h1>Titre1</h1>`. But `IMPORTXML()` is used for this xpath, it seems that `h1` is not included in `a`. From this situation, I think that this might be a bug of `IMPORTXML()`. If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Benoit de Combaud I could study from your question. Thank you, too.